# Regex(taking a specific part of one line)

Tags: regex, shell

I wanna take a specific part of one line, like this one below:

`disk = ['C:/ParticionOne/lalala/bebebeb/disk.img], w']`

I wanna take text between the quotes and before the first brackets, like that:

`C:/ParticionOne/lalala/bebebeb/disk.img`

How can i do that? Give me clues of how do that, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the regex

```
(?<=\[')[^\]]*
```

where:

- `(?<=\[)` is a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that our match is preceded by a `[`.
- `[^\]]*` is 0 or more non-`]` characters.

---

This is what the regex looks like:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/g9IBMAjedtTOGEn3)